# How to pass current ID when updating a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I've set up using stored procedures and select and update commands. I would like to update the user id field automatically whenever a row is updated using the existing server-side variable. I've already configured the select and update procedures and commands using the interface and my sql server stored procedures. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GridView` has an attribute named `DataKeyNames`. Try to use it.

Comment: I thought DataKeyNames was only for primary keys. Can you use it for any field?

Comment: Exactly, `DataKeyNames` are for `PK`. and you use this value to update exact row (by PK).

Comment: I can update fields from individual rows just fine. The problem I have is, I want to update the "UpdatedBy" field automatically when a field in that row is updated using the Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") variable from the back-end. I could update it manually very easily if I wanted to.

Comment: Add `<asp:SessionParameter...` to `UpdateParameters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write the currently logged in user into a Session variable:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["UserID"] = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER");
   }
   ```
2. Change the `SqlDataSource` `UpdateParameters` to have a [SessionParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)  which will populate the `UserID` parameter from the session when the update stored procedure is invoked.

   ```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>" UpdateCommand="UpdateStoredProcedure" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
       <UpdateParameters>
           <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
           <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String"  />
           <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String"  />
           <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="UserID" Type="Int32" />
       </UpdateParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   ```